# Passing LoaderInfo to "Main" class from Preloader?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I initially wrote my Main class to read from LoaderInfo to parse some parameters, but then I recently added a Preloader, with that being the "main class".  Is there a clean way to move things over, or to retrieve LoaderInfo?

Comment: This really depends on how you're using your preloader. More details, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it through a function as a reference.